# AmazonS3Client putObject only works on iOS main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AmazonS3Client to putObject. The strange thing is, it only seems to work when I run my putObject code on the iOS main thread.

The code is basically like this:

```
-(void)uploadVideoToS3
{
    S3PutObjectRequest * videoPOR = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:video.onlineVideoID inBucket:video.onlineVideoBucketName];
    videoPOR.contentType = @"video/quicktime";
    videoPOR.data        = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:video.convertedVideoLocalURL];
    videoPOR.delegate    = self;

    // Put the thumbnail and video into the specified s3 
    AmazonS3Client * s3 = [AmazonClientManager s3];

    [s3 putObject:videoPOR];
    [videoPOR  release];
}
```

The bucket exists, I have permissions, etc.  If I simply call

```
[self uploadVideoToS3]
```

in my code (which is off the main thread), the whole video upload method runs (I have some NSLogs to prove this), but I never get any status callbacks, no exceptions are thrown, and the object is never put into its bucket on S3.

When I call the upload function on the main thread like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    [self uploadVideoToS3];
                });
```

I get progress callbacks, everything works, and the object is successfully put into the S3 bucket.

Does anyone know if putObject only works on the iOS main thread? If so, that would be unfortunate since it's typically the UI thread.

Thanks,
Kevin

P.S. I've tried dispatching the function call on a non-main thread with the same failed result.

Comment: with what code did you try to dispatch it to another thread?

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{[self uploadVideoToS3]});`

Comment: found an interesting article on the AWS website.  Using dispatch_async might be the problem.  Not sure, but here you go--> Avoid using dispatch_sync on the main thread as much as possible  .http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1ZZHQHSD0O3SF/Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Asynchronously-Part-IV-Grand-Central-Dispatch-GCD-Best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am thinking that your thread terminates once it finishes sending the request, therefore the callbacks have no thread to go to.  Creating a thread doesn't automatically mean that it just lives forever.  Once it finishes its task, it ends and is reclaimed for the thread pool.  To do this on another thread, you are going to have to design a method which integrates with a run loop.  There is a section on it in the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) in the Apple docs.

Comment: That's a good point. I tried to fix that by doing `dispatch_queue_create` and then `dispatch_release` after the upload is done, but the upload never continues after the queue is created. It sounds like this is still falling victim to your theory? I'll try some other approaches to extend the lifetime of the thread via a run loop, thanks.

Comment: Queues are separate from threads.  Queues will spawn any number of threads, depending on system conditions, to accomplish the block that they are currently working on.

Comment: I see, so I need to persist a thread (NSThread) as opposed to using say, NSOperationQueue?

Comment: That is my theory.  You need a thread which has a main function that is designed to standby for input, or a termination signal.  Otherwise, your code will be executed inline, and when it returns, the thread will terminate (i.e. it has no way to know that it is supposed to wait for async callbacks)

Comment: But before you try that, try moving everything except the actual call to `putObject` before the dispatch call.  That might help since the object will not be created on a separate thread, but simply captured and the work will be done elsewhere.

Comment: I tried this: http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=549 which failed, surprisingly, since they have NSURLConnection callbacks in the NSOperation subclass.

I also tried moving everything except the `putObject` call before the dispatch, but no dice. Trying run loop next.

Comment: I used a runloop to keep the thread alive, and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually that the S3PutObjectRequest runs asynchronously if you set the delegate. The delegate sends its callbacks on the current run loop, which works fine on the main thread, but not on a dispatch queue thread. You have to start your own run loop in order to process the delegates. I'm still trying to decide the best way to manage this.

Of course, I wish they would simply provide synchronous and asynchronous methods rather than magically switching, but this is explained in the AmazonServiceRequest.h header file on the delegate property.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out by keeping the thread alive with a run loop until the upload finished.

Answer (score 2):

**AmazonS3Client's putObject** method blocks the main thread. Even i was facing the problem. But i found a better solution in **S3TransferManager**.

Example Code:

```
AmazonS3Client * s3 = [AmazonClientManager s3];

S3PutObjectRequest * videoPOR =  [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:video.onlineVideoID inBucket:video.onlineVideoBucketName];                  
videoPOR.contentType = @"video/quicktime";
videoPOR.data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:video.convertedVideoLocalURL];

S3TransferManager *manager = [S3TransferManager new];
manager.s3 = s3; 
[manager upload:videoPOR];
```

**S3TransferManager** runs asynchronously. You can find more info on it [here](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads).

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is a tad old, but I just encountered the same problem and wanted to share the solution that I found from: https://github.com/0i0/iOS-Amazon-S3-upload-service.

As people have mentioned, if you call upload your data off of the main thread, then you need to ensure that your thread stays alive. One way to do so is with NSRunLoops. In the following code we see that the do-while loop will access the current thread's run loop and will persist the thread until the upload is complete.

```
-(void)uploadFileWithData:(NSData *)data
                 fileName:(NSString *)fileName
                 progress:(void (^)(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))progressCallback
                  success:(void (^)(id responseObject))successCallback
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureCallback
{

    progress = progressCallback;
    success = successCallback;
    failure = failureCallback;

    _doneUploadingToS3 = NO;


    AmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:kAWSAccessKeyID withSecretKey:kAWSsecret];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString *pathToFile =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kAWSPath,fileName];
        // Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
        S3PutObjectRequest *por = nil;
        por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:pathToFile inBucket:kAWSBucket];
        por.cannedACL = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
        @try {

            por.delegate = self;
            por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
            por.data = data;

            [s3Client putObject:por];
        }
        @catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
            _doneUploadingToS3 = YES;
        }


        do {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        } while (!_doneUploadingToS3);

        por.delegate = nil;
    });

}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
    _doneUploadingToS3 = YES;
    success(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your insight regarding non-main-thread s3 uploads.  I've found didCompleteWithResponse triggers even if the upload fails and haven't found an easy way to determine that it failed.  I'm trying to upload with ObjectPut rights only so the program is unable to fire off an ObjectGet to check if the file exists.